# Admin URL not working. Throws a 404

Tags: magento2, admin-url

My admin url is not working. Im using the same url that is in the env.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using virtualhost? or is it something like http://localhost/magento2/admin ?

Comment: No its a dev server at our hosting provider. It ended up being an oversight on our part. We were given the wrong url. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

This error 404 always come when your files name doesnot match.

**In other words system is unable to find file path** (that occurs when your file names are not matching with each other) recheck your file names in all folder/files

Comment: is this answer helpful ?